# How to add custom soap headers in my java code along with the url?

Tags: soap, java-8

I am trying to add a custom header in my java code which calls a soap web service. All the way I am going right, but I am not able to add the url. Can someone suggest me where I am going wrong?

```
private SOAPMessage createSOAPRequest(String request) throws Exception {

    MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
    InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(request.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage(new MimeHeaders(), stream);
    SOAPHeader header = soapMessage.getSOAPHeader();

    SOAPHeaderElement sessionHeader1 =  soapMessage.getSOAPHeader().addHeaderElement(new QName("www.xyz.com", "Authorization","prov"));
    sessionHeader1.setValue("AUTH_VALUE");

    SOAPHeaderElement sessionHeader2 =  soapMessage.getSOAPHeader().addHeaderElement(new QName("www.xyz.com", "ABC","prov"));
    sessionHeader2.setValue("ABC_VALUE");

    soapMessage.saveChanges();
```

}

What I am getting:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:prov="www.xyz.com">
<soapenv:Header>
  <prov:Authorization>AUTH_VALUE</prov:Authorization>
  <prov:ABC>ABC_VALUE</prov:ABC>
</soapenv:Header>
```

What I want:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:prov="www.xyz.com">
<soapenv:Header>
  <prov:Authorization xmlns:prov="www.xyz.com">AUTH_VALUE</prov:Authorization>
  <prov:ABC xmlns:prov="www.xyz.com">ABC_VALUE</prov:ABC>
</soapenv:Header>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to create [a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code

```
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPEnvelope;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPHeader;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPHeaderElement;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage;

public class TestSoap {

private SOAPMessage createSOAPRequest(String request) throws Exception {

    MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
    SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();

    SOAPEnvelope soapEnvelope = soapMessage.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope();
    soapEnvelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("prov", "www.xyz.com");

    SOAPHeader soapHeader = soapMessage.getSOAPHeader();

    SOAPHeaderElement sessionHeader1 = 
            soapHeader.addHeaderElement(new QName("www.xyz.com", "Authorization", "prov"));
    sessionHeader1.setValue("AUTH_VALUE");

    SOAPHeaderElement sessionHeader2 =  
            soapHeader.addHeaderElement(new QName("www.xyz.com", "ABC","prov"));
    sessionHeader2.setValue("ABC_VALUE");

    return soapMessage;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    TestSoap ts = new TestSoap();

    SOAPMessage soapMessage = ts.createSOAPRequest("hello");
    soapMessage.writeTo(System.out);
}
}
```

This is what I obtain as output (with some breaklines and tabs for readability)

```
 <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                    xmlns:prov="www.xyz.com">
 <SOAP-ENV:Header>
       <prov:Authorization>AUTH_VALUE</prov:Authorization> 
       <prov:ABC>ABC_VALUE</prov:ABC></SOAP-ENV:Header>
 <SOAP-ENV:Body/>
 </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I've notice that if I comment this line, the output change and it's pretty close to your desired one

```
    // soapEnvelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("prov", "www.xyz.com");
```

New output

```
 <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <SOAP-ENV:Header>
     <prov:Authorization xmlns:prov="www.xyz.com">AUTH_VALUE</prov:Authorization> 
     <prov:ABC xmlns:prov="www.xyz.com">ABC_VALUE</prov:ABC>
 </SOAP-ENV:Header>
 <SOAP-ENV:Body/>
 </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I think that javax is optimizing the namespace assignment. If you assign a namespace to the SOAPEnvelope, it applies in all its children if you don't specify the contrary, making the specific attribute redundant. Sadly I've not found documented evidence of such optimizing.

Hope this helps.